# In Flutter 3.x, ReorderableListView is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-reorderable-listview

I'm trying to implement ReorderableListView in my Flutter app. The code is simple:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) => setState(
        () => items.insert(
          newIndex > oldIndex ? newIndex -= 1 : newIndex,
          items.removeAt(oldIndex),
        ),
      );

  var items = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];

  @override
  Widget build(context) => Scaffold(
        body: ReorderableListView(
          onReorder: _onReorder,
          children: items.map((item) {
            var index = items.indexOf(item);
            return ListTile(
              key: Key('$index'),
              tileColor: Colors.white,
              title: Text(item),
              onTap: () {
                // Handle tap
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      );
}
```

I can't make the code work. The items can't be reordered. `flutter --version` command tells me:

```
Flutter 3.3.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 52b3dc25f6 (3 days ago) • 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

And `flutter doctor` tells me:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error with many samples and tutorials all over the internet, I have found the cause: In Flutter 3.x, ReorderableListView will only work if we use `ReorderableDragStartListener`. This is the 1 link that led me to the right direction: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114783. How to use the listener? I have to modify my code, and update the `ListTile` part as follows:

```
ListTile(
  key: Key('$index'),
  tileColor: Colors.white,
  title: Text(item),
  onTap: () {
    // Handle tap
  },
  trailing: ReorderableDragStartListener(
    index: index,
    child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
  ), 
)
```

I hope this answer will help people, and no one gets through all the frustrating hours like I did.